# How is abstraction realised in a system?

Tags: encapsulation, abstraction

Some say abstraction is achieved through abstract class, while others say it is achieved through encapsulation. I am confused, would someone advise?

Comment: This might be a better fit for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 0):

'Abstraction' is a very vague word covering many.many ideas in programming (and system design)

abstract classes are a very concrete mechanism in some languages.

encapsulation is a common object oriented design pattern used in some languages

Are these 2 models used for abstraction, yes. Are they the only ones, no.